# Redmine And Bitbucket Git

Tags: git, bitbucket, redmine

I am trying to link my existing remote bitbucket git repository to redmine repository tracker. In other words, I'd like to be able to push commits to bitbucket such as

```
commit -m "Updated Class X Relations, #432, 3h"
```

and have this update my redmine installation to read that Issue 432 has 3 hours worked. However, I am not able to register my remote bitbucket.

Here's the desired setup.

Development Machine ----> Bitbucket (Git) ----> RedMine.

It's a private repo and its free. Otherwise I would have used Github.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a plugin to update Redmine when a BitBucket git repository receives a push. The [redmine_bitbucket_hook code](https://github.com/milkfarm/redmine_bitbucket_hook) contains installation instructions. In short:

1. Install the [BitBucket Hook plugin](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_bitbucket_hook) on your Redmine server
2. Create a mirror clone of your git repository on your Redmine server
3. Associate your repository to a project through the Redmine interface
4. Create a webhook through the BitBucket interface to notify Redmine

Answer (score 0):

I am trialling Redmine and do not want to have the entire repository sitting on the Redmine machine, which happens with the plugins eg. http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_bitbucket. I have however, just come up with something that may solve yours (and my) problem: https://zapier.com/zapbook/bitbucket/redmine/. If kept to a low frequency the service is free (see pricing).